# canonical page support on Plone

Tags: seo, plone

I have a site with content that is being indexed by Google in 2, 3 or 4 different ways using the following variations:

```
http://site/folder/page
http://site/folder/page/
http://site/folder/page/view
```

and so on...

according to Google, this can be solved using **rel="canonical"** to indicate which of the above is the canonical page:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

do we have native support for this in Plone?

if not, how do you deal with this? **robots.txt**? redirections on your web server?

Comment: I wonder: is deploying a sitemap is any help for this?

Comment: sitemap doesn't help with this; actually we're checking the Plone standard sitemap to see if it is not causing issues; I know that some listing templates are causing it because the have links ending with '/' and '/view/' in some cases.

Comment: I don't see what's off topic about this question, so why was it closed ?

Comment: Register a simple viewlet in the IHtmlHead viewlet manager that returns canonical_object_url() from plone_context_state.

But in my experience Google ignores the <link rel="canonical"> ...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Quintagroup folks have addressed this with http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/wiki/qSEOptimizer and http://plone.org/products/quintagroup.canonicalpath.

It would be nice to PLIP something sensible into the core one of these days. SEO-friendliness has long been a core value of Plone.

Comment: thanks, Jon! I'll test it and, if it works, I'll accept your answer.